# favicon.ico missing of size 32x32 48x48 although it's declared

Tags: html, favicon

I added to my website all the favicons that it needs and checked with realfavicongenerator until I saw this:

```
favicon.ico is missing some icons of recommended sizes (16x16, 32x32, 48x48)
```

It's soo strange. I already declared here:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="48x48" href="/favicon-48x48.png">
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct path?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a mistake but on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp the 'sizes' attribute on links is marked as not supported by any browsers

Answer (score 4):

RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking.

This message is really about a file named `favicon.ico`. The files you mentions are three PNG files, so basically you are not acting on the same resources.

What you can do:

- [Rely on RealFaviconGenerator to generate your favicon](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) (files and HTML code). Of course, the output of RFG passes the favicon checker.
- [Generate `favicon.ico` as specified by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/gg491740(v=vs.85)#site-icons-in-internet-explorer-9). To do this, you can use RealFaviconGenerator and only take the generated `favicon.ico`.
- Ignore this warning message. As simple as this. `favicon.ico` is less and less used, so it becomes more and more pragmatic to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, of course, but still.

As philippe_b said, here we are talking about the ico format.

One ICO file contains one or more icons of different sizes and resolutions. The icon size can be any, but square icons with sides of 16, 32 and 48 pixels are most commonly used. Icons with the size are also used 24, 40, 60, 72, 92, 108, 128 pixels.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)

Your ICO container probably does not contain the specified dimensions.